# Pampered Chef taco shell maker stoneware with cracks. O.K. to use?

Tags: equipment, mexican-cuisine, kitchen-safety, stoneware

I bought 2 taco shell makers stoneware that have some hairline cracks in them. Will it be safe to use them?

Here is a picture:[image: picture of cracks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Pampered Chef customer service; they asked for a photo, and they determined that it was a defect and they are sending me a new replacement.  So they are being on the safe side.

Answer (score 2):

Unless, I'm not seeing something in the photo, those appear to be scratches and not cracks.  I don't see any reason to doubt the integrity of the stoneware.